# Upgrade a project to Webpack2, VUEJS2 and integrate Gulp

Tags: webpack, gulp, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-2

I'm kind new at webpack / vue.js and learning currently this subjects.
I'm quite familiar with grunt / gulp as I worked before with angular projects.

I would like to upgrade a project here that is a VueJS Boilerplate that use Babel / ES2015 : 
https://github.com/patrickheng/vuejs-webpack-boilerplate/

That I plan to use with a ThreeJS WEBGL Lib integration that is available here (which is made from the previous boilerplate) : 
https://github.com/patrickheng/vuejs-threejs-webpack-boilerplate

For the first boilerplate link, I would like to upgrade it to :

- Webpack 2
- VueJS2
- Integrate Gulp > ES2015 way

Is it possible for someone to specify me with quite much details all steps required to accomplish this without errors at the end and following good practices ?

Thanks anyway.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

Comment: You can check how I did it here https://github.com/bedakb/vuewp - It's webpack 1, but with some small modifications It should work with Webpack 2.
Personally I used gulp on this project only because there is PHP, when I am working with full js stack, I'm using webpack for everything

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @yev, I also checked already that repo, but I really need to update the one I linked.

Comment: @Belmin thanks also for your answer but webpack2 require migration steps to be able to run (accordingly to webpack migration process webpage). You could say "Why don't you just follow the informations on the webpack migration webpage ? It's because there is Babel and some other packages to update also and because of my poor knowledge on the subject. That's why I ask someone maybe that did it already if they can provide some good guidelines with examples. Finally, Webpack and Gulp are different and can be used together.

Comment: Also, Gulp is a task manager and Webpack is a bundler. It makes no sense to me to say you use one for php and the other one for full stack js.

Comment: When you are working with JS Stack only, depending on your needs, you can use webpack for start node server (webpack dev server), hot module reloading, bundling, optimize assets, minify them and do bunch of other stuff.Webpack is huge and much more than module bundler ;)

Comment: Ok that makes more sense :)

Comment: I managed to start webpack2 upgrade, blocked at the end of process with babelrc stage-0 experimental and webpack-hot-middleware. All details included here : https://github.com/patrickheng/vuejs-webpack-boilerplate/pull/3